# PyLint Error: Probably a beginner's mistake

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I know this might be a over repeated question but I'm having troubles with package import process in python for VSCode.

I don't really understand the logic behind the error that keeps popping out although i pip install the packages i need.

For this specific task, I'm trying to import matlib to plot a chart of some crypto time series i already acquired.

I don't know why, no matter what i do ( even setting autocomplete paths ecc in settings.json) I keep getting this error: {

```
"message": "Unable to import 'matplotlib'".
```

I'm not using a  virtualenv for the simple reason I don't know how to and this might complicate things for a beginner like me.

The complete error code is this.

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Main Client/Documents/CRYPTOBOT/api_request/request.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "import-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Unable to import 'matplotlib'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 12,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 12,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

If anyone could kindly and patiently explain why this happens I might learn how to avoid this in future. Please don't tell me that I have to do everything up from scratch because I think I could cry

Comment: You're making a request? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: did u installled matplotlib correctly??

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if you've installed matplotlib to current used python environment. Open a new **integrated** Terminal and run `pip show matplotlib` to see its location. If it's not under the `current_used_python\lib\site-packages`, reinstall it.
[image]

2.If the location is right, check if the module is complete and not lack of components. Turn to the folder `site-packages`, delete files related to matplotlib, then reinstall it to see if the error goes away.